# How to create Instagram-like "pop tags"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on a solution where users can shop items they see on an image. I want to show Instagram-like "pop tags" when users click the image, displaying brand name, item name and a thumbnail of the product.
[**Here's an example.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d63lh.png)

I can make the tags "pop up" on click, but I can't seem to figure out how to make sure the tags don't overlap and don't go beyond the image. The position of the tags are done via. absolute position and percentage.

```
.popTag { position: absolute; top: 46%; left: 23% }
```

So my question is:
In CSS or Javascript (jQuery), how do I make it so that tags automatically orient themselves so they don't overlap and so they don't go beyond the image.
[This is what it looks like right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmDHM.png)

Comment: I honestly think you are going to have to position them using absolute positioning as well as calculating how big they can be. Probably would easier to build a UI to let an actual human place them.

Comment: You might want to borrow some ideas from game development. If you look up "collision detection" it might give you a few good pointers on where to go. That itself will let you detect overlapping tags, but "collision resolution" is going to be a little more involved.

Comment: UI placement won't be possible for now, as I use a Wordpress ACF addon to tag the items. It'll have to be frontend based. I'll try to look into collision detection. Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: You could define 4 classes: above, toTheRight, below, toTheLeft. You could apply the classes by checking if the tag is already there, you can check that by calling elementFromPoint (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint). If for whatever reason they are still overlapped, you could always manipulate the z-index on hover. Would that work?

Comment: Hey Lukasz, thank you for your answer. I'm admittedly not the most savvy JS developer, but I'll definitely check it out. Dumb question: As the tags will have different widths, will your method still work?